# Prefiltering techniques for 3d intersection testing

Tags: 3d

I'm making a plugin in maxscript to detect mesh self intersection.

At first I just looped all edges vs all triangles (excluding pairs with shared vertices) but that was horrificly slow (1h+ on 6k vert test mesh)

Then I tested the bounding boxes of all the edges and faces first, that cut it down to ~3 min

Then I sorted all the edges and faces into a 3d grid first and only tested the primitives against others within their bucket, the edges and faces can also span multiple buckets. That cut it down to ~6 seconds

Thats the end of my ideas though and its still nowhere near as fast as I need it (<100ms)

Are there any other prefiltering techniques for me to implement?

I'd like to avoid moving to another language if at all possible since even though maxscript is horrible, the SDK's for .net and c++ are even worse, its all an undocumented mess.

Comment: The c++ sdk is far from undocumented, it's not perfect but nowhere near as bad as the .net sdk.

Answer (score 3):

I like the suggestion for the octree but I actually believe you can whip your 3d grid implementation into shape. I've done similar things testing self-intersection with meshes spanning millions of verts in milliseconds using that same basic algorithm. That was in C++ and I utilized multiple threads but I doubt maxscript is *that* much slower so as to take 6 seconds on a mesh just spanning 6k verts.

> > As noted in the comments I do absolutely expect MaxScript to be slower, but your case is processing something like 1,000 triangles/sec, while my former cases (and this was on older hardware) was processing something like 80 million triangles/sec (~80,000 times faster) using the same algorithm. I can understand if C++ is a few hundred times faster than MaxScript, but 80,000 times faster probably implies that something else going on like perhaps explosive memory use described below combined with a boatload of cache misses and possibly grid cell sizes that are way too small causing the triangles to be inserted into far more cells (the combo of all four could definitely explain this type of performance difference). And I imagine memory use isn't that big of a concern as long as it's not insane given this type of "build data structure, use it for intersection tests, toss away" one-time use case.

The grid actually isn't bad for self-intersection tests because if you build an octree first, it's a bit more expensive to build usually and you end up having to often drill down to the leaves anyway to perform those self-intersection tests. With the grid you might traverse through some empty cells but the grid is much more cache-friendly to traverse provided the cells are laid out contiguously.

> > On further thought the grid should be theroetically more optimal than octree in this particular case detecting self-intersections, because if you imagine the work required to detect colliding/intersecting triangles for a given triangle, the grid resolves this in constant time, while the octree would do it in logarithmic time... but moreover the octree is sorta doing the same thing, drilling down to the leaf nodes of the tree to check for the triangles in the same cell(s), so to speak. It does have the benefit that it might not have to split nodes as much leading to fewer cells to check in some cases, but then the practical side kicks in where tree node traversal doesn't tend to be nearly as cache-friendly as cell traversal in the grid. And then on top of that, building the tree tends to be more expensive with insertions requiring logarithmic time as well as a lot more work in each iteration splitting cells and so forth.

The main thing I suspect you are doing which I've seen a lot in VFX which slows down spatial indexes to a crawl (whether we're talking a grid or spatial hash or octree or loose octree or kd-tree or BVH) while making them take hundreds of times more memory than they should is storing a variable-sized container with each tree node or grid cell/bucket. That tends to be a massive performance killer in terms of building the structure and traversing the tree, since it tends to be rather explosive in memory use and causes cache misses all over the place when you consider how many cells or nodes these spatial indexes can have and multiply that with the size of a variable-sized sequence. I've actually managed to reduce an octree implementation I discovered in a legacy codebase from requiring 1.2 gigs of RAM down to a little over 3 megabytes just using this basic technique covered below with almost proportional reductions in time spent in the operation*.

> > - That particular case was in C++ and had each octree node storing its own instance of `std::vector` where it started off inserting everything to the root node and then splitting it and transferring portions of that vector to the vectors below. Moreover it didn't factor in that removing elements or even completely clearing a vector doesn't deallocate its dynamic memory, so it ended up just exponentially using more memory than required.

The solution is just store one variable-sized container for the entire grid (or tree if you choose to go with octree; this is applicable either way). Store all the elements you need in one gigantic random-access sequence.

Now an easy way you can "emulate" having a separate variable-sized container/list per node or grid cell (without allocating separate memory blocks and keeping track of their size and so forth) is to then store an index with each element which allows you to skip around the sequence (array, i.e.) in a singly-linked list sort of fashion, like so:

[image]

Except all the nodes are allocated and stored contiguously in one gigantic array, and we're using the indices to skip through the array. And each cell stores nothing but a 32-bit integer for an index into the array (the head of the list). The data can be as simple as this:

```cpp
struct Grid
{
    struct GridCell
    {
        // Index pointing to the first element in the cell
        // or -1 if the cell is empty.
        int first;
    };

    struct GridElement
    {
        // Index pointing to the original element (ex: triangle) outside 
        // the grid.
        int element;

        // Index pointing to the next element in the cell or -1 if
        // this is the last element in the cell.
        int next;
    };

    // Stores all the cells in the grid.
    std::vector<GridCell> cells;

    // Stores all the elements in the grid.
    std::vector<GridElement> elements;

    // Maybe some data for grid and cell size/AABBs.
    ...
};
```

If you do it this way, I'd be surprised if you don't get to a fraction of a second at least on the first try provided your cell size is reasonable in proportion to the size of the mesh's AABB*.

> > - There is admittedly some fiddling to the cell size you use for a grid to often get the most out of it. In my case I used like a trial-and-error approach where I constructed a test case and benchmark involving a variety of meshes and tried to come up with a simple function to try to quickly approximate a decent cell size based on the resolution of the mesh combined with the size of its AABB which would give optimal times for each test case without benefiting one at the cost of the other. That fiddliness still tends to apply though to some degree even if you use tree structures here, especially with the kind of content you can find in VFX (which isn't always cleaned up very much and could have coincident polygons and such) to limit the tree depth, for example. I tend to favor grids a lot in VFX even in cases where trees seem more optimal theoretically since the disgusting kind of content that hasn't been cleaned up that you can encounter here can cause those types of structures to want to split indefinitely (even loose variants and ones that split tris/polys where nodes split: imagine 30 triangles right on top of each other sharing all three vertex positions), whereas the grid at least doesn't choke like that on those cases.

Comment: Maxscript can in fact sometimes be much slower than c++ for the same algorithm.

Comment: Understably very much so (I wouldn't expect otherwise), but I'm thinking if it takes 6 seconds to process 6k triangles (~1k triangles/sec) while I can process about 2 million in 25 milliseconds (~80m triangles/sec), that C++ is probably not 80,000 times faster, but more likely that the implementation is probably doing what I tend to encounter a lot with spatial indexes that really throw off their performance. If C++ was 100 times faster or even 500 times faster than Maxscript, I would understand, but 80,000 times faster seems like there's something else going on there.

Comment: Yeah, x100-x500 sounds about right.

Comment: Oh its been a long while, little update: I tried tracking down the performance problems in MaxScript for a while and did have some breakthroughs. For one, the native structure that the vertices came in was hundreds of times slower to access than a plain array with a controlled type and over a thousand times slower than a custom .net structure I dynamically created in MS but in the end, it still wasn't enough since the vertex conversion step ended up taking longer than the actual collider part and there was nothing I could do about it.

Comment: I since moved the project to C++ with the SDK and decided to try out C++AMP, implemented the octree instead of a grid since it was more convenient even though I did measure the grid to be somewhat faster when properly optimized. But at that point it didn't matter since I also found a better way to perform self-intersection testing through a special type of ray-tracing that only works on completely enclosed meshes (which was OK for me). Bottom line is, I got it down to less than 1ms, most of which is transferring data through and from the GPU.

Comment: Very nice! If you ever have need to implement such spatial structures again in CPU/GPU, I've often found it helpful to shrink the size of the node or cell/bucket to a minimum -- often like 8 bytes or less unless the node/cell stores an AABB along with (in which case it'd inevitably be a bit larger).

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, it's common to use an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). This divides the 3D world into 3D octants, then further divides each of those into smaller octants, etc. It sounds like it's similar to what you've done, but it might offer some improvement. At each level of the tree, you're dealing with 1/8th the space of the previous level, so it converges on a set of important vertices pretty quickly.